# Responsive Email (Outlook 2016) issues

Tags: html, html-email, email-templates, outlook-2016

I used [this responsive email template](https://github.com/charlesmudy/responsive-html-email-template) to design a tabular report email template but unfortunately it renders horribly on outlook desktop 2016.

I'll appreciate any form of help I can get to make my template look better on outlook desktop.
Here is the code snippet for the tabular area of the template:

```
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top">
    <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
          <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
          <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="flexibleContainer">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top" width="600" class="flexibleContainerCell" style="background-color:#dd4f05;">
                <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style='table-layout:fixed'>
                  <thead style="color: #ffffff; line-height: 200%; font-family:Tahoma,Verdana,Segoe,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; text-align: right; font-weight: bold">
                    <col width=6 />
                    <col width=10 />
                    <col width=6 />
                    <tr>
                      <th align="left">Category</th>
                      <th>Novemeber Spend</th>
                      <th align="left">Vs October </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="color: #ffffff; line-height: 200%; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Segoe,sans-serif; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 20px;" align="left">Food</td>
                      <td align="right" style="font-size: 30px;">&#8358;1,234,567.00</td>
                      <td align="right">
                        <div style="font-size: 25px;color: #008000; float: left">&#9650;</div>
                        <p style="float: left; margin: 0; font-size: 20px">23%</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 20px;" align="left">Gadgets</td>
                      <td align="right" style="font-size: 30px;">&#8358;901,234.00</td>
                      <td align="right">
                        <div style="font-size: 25px;color: #008000; float: left">&#9650;</div>
                        <p style="float: left; margin: 0; font-size: 20px">74%</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 20px;" align="left">Entertainment</td>
                      <td align="right" style="font-size: 30px;">&#8358;789,012.00</td>
                      <td align="right">
                        <div style="font-size: 25px;color: #008000; float: left">&#9650;</div>
                        <p style="float: left; margin: 0; font-size: 20px">23%</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 20px;" align="left">School Fees</td>
                      <td align="right" style="font-size: 30px;">&#8358;567,890.00</td>
                      <td align="right">
                        <div style="font-size: 25px;color: #008000; float: left">&#9650;</div>
                        <p style="float: left; margin: 0; font-size: 20px">10%</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-size: 20px;" align="left">Health Care</td>
                      <td align="right" style="font-size: 30px;">&#8358; 345,678.00</td>
                      <td align="right">
                        <div style="font-size: 25px;color: #008000; float: left">&#9650;</div>
                        <p style="float: left; margin: 0; font-size: 20px">6%</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

How it looks on web version of gmail and yahoo:
[image: Gmail Screen Shot]

How it looks on outlook desktop client (Horrible):
[image: Outlook Desktop Client]

Comment: Have you tried adding display:inline-block to the div?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest using display: inline-block as floats do not work at all with Outlook. This is [a great reference](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css) as to what does and does not work with emails.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the  in that last column to a span, remove the float: left from both it and the paragraph - in fact, remove the paragraph tag entirely, and add font-size to the  tag, which should be left aligned, not right. You're giving too many contradictory instructions for poor little Outlook to follow.